# python ctypes winerror -4021

Tags: python, ctypes

I shifting an vb project to python, the setup for the com interface is working, now I want to read the data:

```
# int FEISC_0xB0_ISOCmd( int iReaderHnd, unsigned char cBusAdr, unsigned char* cReqData, int iReqLen, unsigned char* cRspData, int* iRspLen, int iDataFormat )

feisc.FEISC_0xB0_ISOCmd.argtypes = c_int, c_ubyte, c_char_p, c_int, c_char_p, c_int, c_int


rspData = create_string_buffer(512);
rspDatalen = 0
iBack = feisc.FEISC_0xB0_ISOCmd(iReader, 255, b'0100', 4, rspData, rspDataLen, 0x01)
```

I got the following error:

```
OSError: [WinError -4021] Windows Error 0x%X
```

what does this error mean?

I changed to feisc = WinDLL('FeIsc') and now I got an error from the dll that some pointer is 0. how can I rdpatlen as a int* to the function?

Comment: `int* iRspLen` argtype should be `POINTER(c_int)`. Also I;m not sure if it's OK to pass `b'0100'`, you should create a string buffer from it.

Comment: ok, with the POINTER in the argtypes setup it works, pointer is found and I got another error. first I have a loop at the API

Comment: @CristiFati Passing `b'0100'` is fine if it is an input (read-only) parameter, which `cReqData` probably is.  `ctypes` knows how to marshal the data properly, but since Python strings are immutable they can't be written to.  The API should be more properly defined as `const char* cReqData` if it is input-only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`iRspLen` should be type `POINTER(c_int)`.  For output parameters you need to create ctypes data instances to hold the result.  Below I'm guessing that `cRspDataLen` should be initialized with the size of the response buffer on input and likely is updated with the actual size on output.

```
# int FEISC_0xB0_ISOCmd(int iReaderHnd, unsigned char cBusAdr, unsigned char* cReqData, int iReqLen, unsigned char* cRspData, int* iRspLen, int iDataFormat)
feisc.FEISC_0xB0_ISOCmd.argtypes = c_int,c_ubyte,c_char_p,c_int,c_char_p,POINTER(c_int),c_int

cReqData = b'0100'
rspData = create_string_buffer(512);
iRspLen = c_int(len(rspData))
iBack = feisc.FEISC_0xB0_ISOCmd(iReader,255,cReqData,len(cReqData),rspData,iRspLen, 0x01)
```